# How to add onto a list tuple pairs

Tags: python

Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.

For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

Code:

```
numbers = [6, 7, 8, 3]
k = 14

def add_to_k(numbers_list,k_value):
    truth = False
    pairs = []
    for i in numbers_list:
        for l in numbers_list:
            added = i + l
            if added == k_value:
                if numbers_list.index(i) == numbers_list.index(l):
                    pass
                else:
                    paired = str(i) + ", " + str(l)
                    pairs += paired
                    truth = True
    if truth == True:
        print("Two numbers in the list added together is {}: ".format(k_value) + str(pairs))
    else:
        print("Sorry, none give " + str(k_value))
add_to_k(numbers,k)
```

This code returns an output like this:

```
Two numbers in the list added together is 17: ['6', ',', ' ', '8', '8', ',', ' ', '6']
```

but I want it to give me the two numbers that add to 17 in tuples. For example, [(1,2),(3,4)]

Comment: use `pairs.append`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you should append the values to `paired` has changed in below code

```
numbers = [6, 7, 8, 3]
k = 14


def add_to_k(numbers_list,k_value):
    truth = False
    pairs = []
    for i in numbers_list:
        for l in numbers_list:
            added = i + l
            if added == k_value:
                if numbers_list.index(i) == numbers_list.index(l):
                    pass
                else:
                    ## modification done here
                    paired = (i,l)
                    pairs.append(paired)
                    ## modification end
                    truth = True
    if truth == True:
        print("Two numbers in the list added together is 17: " + str(pairs))
    else:
        print("Sorry, none give " + str(k_value))
add_to_k(numbers,k)
```

output:

```
Two numbers in the list added together is 17: [(6, 8), (8, 6)]
```

### Different Approach Using `itertools`

```
import itertools
```

**Option 1:** If you want to produce the unique set of numbers, then you use `itertools.combinations`

```
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(numbers, 2))
```

**Option 2:** If you want to produce the all combination set of numbers, then you use `itertools.permutations`

```
combinations = list(itertools.permutations(numbers,2))
```

Then check the sum of values to `k`

```
output = [comb for comb in combinations if comb[0]+comb[1] == k]
output
```

**Option 1:** output using`itertools.combinations`

```
[(6, 8)]
```

**Option 2:** output using `itertools.permutations`

```
[(6, 8),(8, 6)]
```

Comment: @ewe , Please upvote my solution if you found useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension should work.

```
li = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k=14

res = k in [a+b for a in li for b in li] 

print (res)
```

Output:

```
True
```